# How do I get dimensions of an image SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have an image which is being set through:

```
var oImage = new sap.m.Image({
    id: image0,
    src: "img/image0.jpg"
});
```

I want to figure out the width and height of the image ?

I have tried `oImage.getWidth()` and `oImage.getHeight()` but those return empty. I have also tried `parseInt(oImage.getWidth())` and `parseInt(oImage.getHeight())` but those return `NaN`.

Comment: Make sure the image is init correctly. Then your oImage.getWidth() and oImage.getHeight() will work :)

Comment: what do you mean that image is init correctly?

Comment: would you attack screenshot of your oImage object or atleast the output of console.log(oImage);

Comment: I would like to know how to get the dimension of image.What steps / code i have to use.

Comment: Like I said oImage.getWidth() and oImage.getHeight() works as long as your object is sap.m.Image.
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are empty because you haven't set them yet. Both `getHeight` and `getWidth` return the set values not the default height and width of the image. Have a look at **[Image Control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Image/controlProperties)**.

```js
var oImage = new sap.m.Image("image0", {
  src: "img/load.gif",
  height: "30vh",
  width: "30vw"
});
```

This `oImage.getWidth()` will return `"30vw"`

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have not specified with and height of the image, you will have to use the DOM to get the details of the image. Try the following code in your controller:

```
var image = this.byId("image0"); 
var oDomRef = image.getDomRef()
console.log(oDomRef .width, oDomRef .height);
```

It will give the image width and height in px.